# ¿Por qué tengo que recargar la página para que detecte el session_start en PHP?

Tags: php, session

tengo una página alojada en mi servidor. Y esta se debe de mostrar si la variable $_SESSION existe.
El problema es que, cuando alguien entra, a menudo la página no se muestra y es necesario que recarguen la página para poder verla.
¿Alguien sabe porqué llega a pasar esto?

```
<?php
  session_start();
  if( isset($_SESSION['userID']) ) {
 ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/comunidav.ico" href="../../img/favicon/comunidav.ico" 
     sizes="32x32">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../css/stylesLoged.css">
    <title>Verificación de cuenta</title>
</head>
```

Comment: Primero que nada, el php es incorrecto, corrigelo.

Comment: Es solo la primera parte de php, al final se cierra correctamente

Comment: Por eso, no veo en que momento tratas de mostrar la variable.

Comment: No trato de mostrarla, trato de impedir que se vea la página si no existe una sesión.
El problema es que cuando llegan a esa página si existe una y marca como si no existiera

Comment: entonces agrega el archivo que abre esta pagina, y completa el codigo php de esta misma, algo estas haciendo mal